# Closing EntityManager after each db operation when using HikariCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entitymanager, hikaricp

I am using EntityManager along with HikariCP for database operations. Should I need to close the entity manager after each operation?
Only one database operation is there per request

```
@Autowired
@PersisitentContext(unitname="datasource2")
private EntityManager entityManager

function() {

entityManager.createQuery(......);

entityManage.close(); // Is this required???



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to close it before returning from the method that created it. A common approach is to embed EM in a try/catch/finally block, invoking em.close(); in the finally case.

Comment: EntityManger instance is not created in the function. It is autowired and is a class variable.

Comment: As in this case the container creates the EntityManager for us , This means the container is in charge of beginning the transaction, as well as committing or rolling it back.
Similarly, the container is responsible for closing the EntityManager, so it's safe to use without manual cleanups. Even if we try to close a container-managed EntityManager, it should throw an IllegalStateException.